# Calculate angle with Atan2

Tags: c#, sfml

I am trying to make a line (rectangle) to rotate to my mouse positions
My code is:

```
double xDiff = playerPosX - Mouse.GetPosition().X;
double yDiff = playerPosY - Mouse.GetPosition().Y;
double dir = Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180 / Math.PI;
line.Rotation = Convert.ToSingle(dir);
```

However this does not rotate correctly to my mouse position.
How it rotates:https://imgur.com/a/KNvVX
I hope someone is able to help.

Edit: I had to change the way it gets the mouse position to: Mouse.GetPosition(Game.window).X and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that Mouse.GetPosition is giving you X, Y position in the same frame of reference to playerPosX/Y (ie - Is the mouse position with respect to the screen coordinates & player position with respect to application window)

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Comment: The mouse.GetPosition takes the coordinates not from the application screen but the whole screen. Any way to change this?

Comment: You may be able to add your solution as an answer & mark it correct - that would help anybody else with the same issue when searching SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the mouse position from the application window (which was causing it not to work) just use Mouse.getPosition(yourwindow).x/y and it should work fine.